# Passing column information to SparkSession within withColumn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have  a simple df with 2 columns, as shown below,

```
+------------+---+
|file_name   |id |
+------------+---+
|file1.csv   |1  |
|file2.csv   |2  |
+------------+---+

root
 |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I wish to add a 3rd column with the `count()` from each file specified in the `file_name` column
These are large files so I wish to go for a Spark based approach for getting the count() from each file.

Assuming originalDF is the above df,

I have tried:

```
 dfWithCounts =  originalDF.withColumn("counts", lit(spark.read.csv(lit(col('file_name'))).count))
```

but this seems to be throwing error.

```
Column is not iterable
```

Is there way I can achieve this?

I'm using Spark 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a Spark job from within another Spark job. Assuming that the file list is not super huge you can collect `originalDF` to the driver and spawn individual jobs to count lines from there.

```
val dfWithCounts = originalDF.collect.map { r =>
  (r.getString(0), r.getInt(1), spark.read.csv(r.getString(0)).count)
}.toSeq.toDF("file_name", "id", "count")
```

Optionally you can use [Scala parallel collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) to run these jobs in parallel.

```
val dfWithCounts = originalDF.collect.par.map { r =>
  (r.getString(0), r.getInt(1), spark.read.csv(r.getString(0)).count)
}.toSeq.seq.toDF("file_name", "id", "count")
```